# Using Chef to enable IIS

Tags: chef-infra

Trying to teach myself Powershell and Chef, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple

So I'm actually using a Server Manager program called Chef. But the scripts run using PS interpreter. I ensured that the ServerManager module is imported, I'm running PS with Admin priv, and I'm running the 64 bit version of PS.

Here's my script to enable IIS if it isn't already

```
powershell_script 'Install IIS' do
  code 'Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server'
  guard_interpreter :powershell_script
  not_if "(Get-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server).Installed"
end
```

When I run it I receive the following error msg:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo> chef-apply .\webserver.rb
Recipe: (chef-apply cookbook)::(chef-apply recipe)
  * powershell_script[Install IIS] action run

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'powershell_script[Install IIS]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of "powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -InputFormat
None -File "C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chef-script20141224-1308-ftog62.ps1" ----
    STDOUT:
    STDERR: The term 'Add-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    ---- End output of "powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -InputFormat No
ne -File "C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chef-script20141224-1308-ftog62.ps1" ----
    Ran "powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -InputFormat None -File "C:/Us
ers/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chef-script20141224-1308-ftog62.ps1" returned 1

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In .\webserver.rb

  1: powershell_script 'Install IIS' do
  2:   code 'Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server'
  3:   guard_interpreter :powershell_script
  4:   not_if "(Get-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server).Installed"
  5: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in .\webserver.rb:1:in `run_chef_recipe'

powershell_script("Install IIS") do
  action "run"
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :powershell_script
  command "\"powershell.exe\" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -InputFormat None -File \"C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chef-script20141224-1308-ftog62.ps1\""
  backup 5
  returns 0
  code "Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server"
  interpreter "powershell.exe"
  cookbook_name "(chef-apply cookbook)"
  recipe_name "(chef-apply recipe)"
  not_if "(Get-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server).Installed"
end

[2014-12-24T09:37:19-08:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to C:/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-12-24T09:37:19-08:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: powershell_script[Install IIS] ((chef-apply coo
kbook)::(chef-apply recipe) line 1) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0
], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -InputFormat None
 -File "C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chef-script20141224-1308-ftog62.ps1" ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: The term 'Add-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable prog
ram. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
---- End output of "powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -InputFormat None -
File "C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chef-script20141224-1308-ftog62.ps1" ----
Ran "powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -InputFormat None -File "C:/Users/
ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/chef-script20141224-1308-ftog62.ps1" returned 1
```

Comment: let me know if you need more help than what i provided below...

Answer (score 3):

For those of you, who tries to go through Chef Basics tutorial and are stuck with this error -

It seems that the tutorial assumes that you have PowerShell 3.0, where modules are auto-imported when needed. This is not the case for PowerShell 2.0, where you have to import them explicitly in your cookbook.

First, make sure you are running PowerShell 2.0 by running `$psversiontable`.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5477
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Pay attention to the value of `PSVersion` - if it is not `2.0` you probably have some other problem.

Here is the updated script that imports right module:

```
powershell_script 'Install IIS' do
  code <<-EOH
  Import-Module ServerManager
  Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server
  EOH
  guard_interpreter :powershell_script
  not_if "Import-Module ServerManager; (Get-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server).Installed"
end
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Just to add...with a PSVersion of 4.0 I also have the same issue - and this worked! I did not need to add the import statement in the not_if block...just the code block

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `windows_feature` (built-in to chef), because of that this isn't really the opportunity you think it is:

---

### **recipe:**

```
%w{ IIS-WebServerRole IIS-WebServer NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45 IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic IIS-WebServerManagementTools IIS-ManagementConsole IIS-ApplicationDevelopment IIS-ApplicationInit IIS-ISAPIFilter IIS-ISAPIExtensions IIS-NetFxExtensibility45 IIS-ASPNET45 IIS-ManagementScriptingTools IIS-HttpRedirect }.each do |feature|
  windows_feature feature do
    action :install
  end
end
```

The list is all the features i'm enabling...you could do just 1 feature like so:

```
windows_feature 'IIS-WebServerRole' do
   action :install
end
```

but the above won't be all the things you need for IIS...
You can find very specific information here: https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/windows